# Date extraction from datepickers

Tags: vba, excel, datepicker, excel-2010

I have 2 datepickers in my sheet "From" and "To". I want to record the date selected from these datepickers in variables and then refer to the input data sheet between the given range and extract data. I have written some code.

```
Sub PITimeseries()
Dim a As Object
Dim b As Object
Dim c As Date
Set a = DTPicker1.Value
Set b = DTPicker2.Value

Sheet9.Select
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, rng1 As Range
Set rng = Range("B5:B71")
Set rng1 = Range("H5:H71")
For Each cell In rng
If cell.Value = a Or cell.Value = b Then
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WBVl.png)
Now I am stuck as to how I will make the corresponding date match cell true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim a As Date, b As Date, c As Date
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, rng1 As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet9")
Set rng = sht.Range("B5:B71")
Set rng1 = sht.Range("H5:H71")

a = DTPicker1.Value
b = DTPicker2.Value

For Each cell In rng
c = CDate(cell.Value)
If c >= a And c <= b Then
    sht.Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value = "True"
Else
    sht.Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value = "False"
End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

So your variable types were kind of wrong and for `OR` only one of the two conditions have to fit. And please dont use `.Select`, always objectify `.Range, .Cells etc.`.

Comment: Thanks mate. I went ahead with a simple month drop down selector rather than a datepicker. But this code definitely helped me. Much thanks!